# UriComponentsBuilder query param and fragment

Tags: spring, relative-path, url-encoding, query-string

I want to generate the following path: **'/app#/fragment1?test=toto'** with spring library [UriComponentsBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html).

What I have tried so far:

```
UriComponentsBuilder ucb = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/app").fragment("fragment1").queryParam("test","toto");

ucb.toUriString(); // -> gives me as result : '/app?test=toto#/fragment1'
```

Any idea how to achieve this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would simply do something like :

```
// first build fragment part
String fragmentWithQueryParams = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/fragment1").queryParam("test","toto").toUriString();

// then generate full path
String fullPath = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/app").fragment(fragmentWithQueryParams).toUriString());

System.out.println(fullPath); // -> "/app#/fragment1?test=toto"
```

Comment: Yes you are right, that's what I did. Build fragment with query params as UriComponent and full path separately. I'll accept your answer